# How do I inform FLEX where the Flare.Prefuse library is?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flare

I'm very new to ActionScript/Flex programming. I have Flex 4.6 and the last Flare.Prefuse update. Flare has a src directory with subdirectories of all the various classes. Compiling sample code produces "Definition flare could not be found" which is understandable. I am just using the command line version of mxmcl to compile the code. What do I need to do to link in the Flare library?

Any help really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `-source-path` and `-library-path` flags for `mxmlc`, documented [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html), or in mxmlc itself with `mxmlc -help library-path source-path`.

Comment: I ended up using this line:

~/bin/flex/bin/mxmlc -include-libraries='build/flare.swc' -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true

and that worked. Thanks for the help! I got my first Flare app working about a minute ago!

Answer (score 1):

The swc for the library should be placed in the "lib" folder under src. That usually does the trick, but that when using Flex builder.